# One mail, multiple content depending the mail address

Tags: php, email

I don't know if it is possible or if it has already been asked.
But here's my problem.
I would like to send a mail to multiple address, and display in the mail, the mail address and some account information according the email address (not only the name).

Ex: 
I send an email to **john@gmail.com**, **jack@gmail.com** & **luke@gmail.com**.

John will see "Hello **John**, ...",
Jack will see "Hello **Jack**, ...",
...

Is it possible to do it by sending a single mail? Or do I need to send 1 mail by account?

PS: I don't know if it can help, but I user PHPMailer.

Comment: Could you show us the code you have to send to one address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to send separate emails to send different content.

If you want to make your life easier, though, you ought to use a template with PHPMailer and provide the necessary data. There are plenty of [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158181/send-html-emails-using-phpmailer-and-html-templates) and [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki) on doing this.

Also note that if you are sending multiple emails you should be using BCC anyway or everyone will see everyone else's email address and you will most likely get hurt for spam.